# How to get column footer data in Angular UI-Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

For example, in this [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20105%20Footer), if there is any way to get the data in the column footer? I'd like to present the total numbers in somewhere else.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the sum for the certain column this way: `$scope.gridApi.grid.columns[column_number].getAggregationValue() // Here I get 281568`

I have created an example here: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/repilunaza/edit?html,js,output)